# Column alias conflict with table names in MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I work on **MS Access 2010 database** and I stumbled upon weird issue with column aliases. I have a query with multiple joins, and I want to name my result columns. However, some aliases result in empty columns.

In my efforts to understand this issue and isolate it, I prepared a query that should display the same column with different aliases, with each alias being a name of existing table or query in my database. Funny enough, 3 of them result in empty columns, (`AS [Analyst]`, `AS [MeetingCompany]`, and `AS [Sector]`), while the others work fine. Note, that `Analyst` table isn't even in this query, but exists in the database.

Is there any rule for column aliases that I'm not aware of? Or is it just an oddity I have to live with and use different aliases?

```
SELECT  Sector.SectorName AS [Analyst], Sector.SectorName AS [vCompanyPrimary], 
Sector.SectorName AS [MeetingCompany], Sector.SectorName AS [Client],
Sector.SectorName AS [ClientContact], Sector.SectorName AS [MeetingClientContact], 
Sector.SectorName AS [Sector], Sector.SectorName AS [vMeetingSectorID], 
Sector.SectorName AS [EventTypeGroup], Sector.SectorName AS [Country], 
Sector.SectorName AS [Area], Sector.SectorName AS [City]
FROM (((((((((((Meeting INNER JOIN Event ON Meeting.EventID = Event.EventID)
 INNER JOIN EventType ON Event.EventTypeID = EventType.ID)
 LEFT JOIN vMeetingSectorID ON Meeting.MeetingID = vMeetingSectorID.MeetingID)
 LEFT JOIN Sector  ON vMeetingSectorID.SectorID = Sector.ID)
 LEFT JOIN City ON City.ID = Meeting.CityID)
 LEFT JOIN Area ON City.AreaID = Area.ID)
 LEFT JOIN Country ON Country.ID = City.CountryID)
 LEFT JOIN EventTypeGroup ON EventType.ID = EventTypeGroup.EventTypeID)
 LEFT JOIN MeetingClientContact ON Meeting.MeetingID = MeetingClientContact.MeetingID)
 LEFT JOIN ClientContact ON MeetingClientContact.ClientContactID = ClientContact.ContactID)
 LEFT JOIN Client ON ClientContact.ClientID = Client.ClientID)
```

**EDIT:**
I managed to find and remove a culprit, but I still don't understand the rules for this limitation. `vMeetingSectorID` is a saved query in Access, and it used tables `Analyst`, `Sector`, and `MeetingCompany`. Once I used aliases for table names in this saved query, all columns are displayed properly. I will be greatful for any hint, so I can avoid these situations in future.

Comment: Simplify to make it easier for everybody to help you, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Is it really too complex? The query works in general (joins are correct), and I only mean that the same column is displayed correctly or not, depending on its alias.

Comment: Well, I didn't really mean too complex, just too much of it. It's so much easier to find a problem if you remove all unrelated stuff first.

Comment: Probably you faced to Access bug and it's specific to your database. At least when I tried to reproduce this on my A2010, it worked fine if I gave multiple aliases to the same column using table names. To be sure that it's not related to corruption please copy all objects to new database and try again. If it won't help it would be great to look at sample database

Answer (score 1):

As you found, you are running into name clashes which can have unexpected results. To avoid in future always use table aliases especially with self-joins and joining queries with same underlying tables. Specifically, the embedded query:

```
LEFT JOIN vMeetingSectorID 
   ON Meeting.MeetingID = vMeetingSectorID.MeetingID
```

Is arguably equivalent to a subquery or derived table:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM ... INNER JOIN ...) AS vMeetingSectorID 
  ON Meeting.MeetingID = vMeetingSectorID.MeetingID
```

And this inner query uses same tables as outer query such as *Sector*. The engine can then have issues associating identifiers especially with a resulting column named, *Sector*, as a table.

Therefore, use table aliases that properly defines the inner and outer query scopes. Plus it makes long queries more compact and readable as shown below. Do the same of course with the query, *vMeetingSectorID*.

```
SELECT  s.SectorName AS [Analyst], s.SectorName AS [vCompanyPrimary], 
        s.SectorName AS [MeetingCompany], s.SectorName AS [Client],
        s.SectorName AS [ClientContact], s.SectorName AS [MeetingClientContact], 
        s.SectorName AS [Sector], s.SectorName AS [vMeetingSectorID], 
        s.SectorName AS [EventTypeGroup], s.SectorName AS [cnty.], 
        s.SectorName AS [Area], s.SectorName AS [City]
FROM (((((((((((Meeting m INNER JOIN Event e ON m.EventID = e.EventID)
INNER JOIN EventType et. ON e.EventTypeID = et.ID)
LEFT JOIN vMeetingSectorID v ON m.MeetingID = v.MeetingID)
LEFT JOIN Sector s ON v.SectorID = s.ID)
LEFT JOIN City cy ON cy.ID = m.CityID)
LEFT JOIN Area a ON cy.AreaID = a.ID)
LEFT JOIN Country n ON n.ID = cy.ID)
LEFT JOIN EventTypeGroup etg ON et.ID = etg.EventTypeID)
LEFT JOIN MeetingClientContact mcc ON m.MeetingID = mcc.MeetingID)
LEFT JOIN ClientContact cc ON mcc.ClientContactID = cc.ContactID)
LEFT JOIN Client c ON cc.ClientID = c.ClientID)
```

Comment: I'm a bit smarter now. Do you know why I can use aliases that are same as table names in my query, but overlapping with subquery causes issues? I think it requires deeper understanding of database engine.

Comment: First please understand two separate items here: table aliases and column aliases. Table aliases are designed for shorthand of table names and advised when re-using tables anywhere in query.

Comment: Column aliases are for end use, even report needs. Once again, you can name column names to *anything* just be sure to avoid collision of other identifiers by using table aliases to associate which sources go with what final columns.